# goodlayers wordpress tabbed content keyboard focus

Tags: jquery, wordpress, keyboard, focus, accessibility

I'm working on a site and 'm tyring to make sure that it can be read by screen readers as much as possible we've run into problem with a tabbed content element that won't receive keyboard focus as it's created with a div.

http://dev-rivervalleypools.pantheonsite.io/pools/vogue-panache/

Unfortunately my javascript isn't great but I found this article - http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201302/making_elements_keyboard_focusable_and_clickable/

and i'm attempting to modify this script below to correct the problem. I'm stuck on setting the click function and i'm not sure if i'm even on the right track.

```
 $('<span>', {
'class': 'button', // So you can style it
role: 'button', // Tell assistive technology it's a button
tabindex: '0', // Make it keyboard focusable
click: function() { // Make something happen when it is clicked
    alert('You clicked me!');
},
keydown: function(e) { // Trigger the click event from the keyboard
    var code = e.which;
    // 13 = Return, 32 = Space
    if ((code === 13) || (code === 32)) {
        $(this).click();
    }
},
html: 'Click me!'
}).appendTo($('#button-container'));
```

Comment: I tried converting each of them to a `<button>` element, but the script is poorly written, so I see why you took this approach. I see your code is looking for a `<span>` but the elements are `<div>`s. I cannot test what you have, but is that the issue?

Comment: What i'm trying to do on the tabbed content of the site is instead of it being a div changing it to a button so that hopefully this script would allow people to use a keyboard to get to the tabbed content. I'm actually not sure if this would be the right approach.

Just right now on the site there is no way using the keyboard to get through the tabbed content which is terrible for accessibility.

Comment: Your code above is looking for a `<span>`. The code on the page use a `<div>`. That may be the issue. Alternatively, a `<button>` still fires a click event when activated with a keyboard (example: http://jsfiddle.net/v1mwzo3o/).